# How to connect two peripheral with same service UUID?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have bluetooth hearing aid. They have different device name and same service UUID.

I want to my app can connect them at the same time. How should I do?

My code just can connect one peripheral.

My code:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    print("Find device： \(String(describing: peripheral.name))")
    guard peripheral.name != nil else {
        return
    }
    guard peripheral.name?.range(of: "HD100-5201000") != nil else {
        return
    }
    guard peripheral.name?.range(of: "HD100-5200526") != nil else {
        return
    }
    central.stopScan()
    if peripheral.name?.range(of: "HD100-5201000") != nil {
        connectPeripheral = peripheral
        connectPeripheral.delegate = self
        centralManager.connect(connectPeripheral, options: nil)
    }
    if peripheral.name?.range(of: "HD100-5200526") != nil {
        connectPeripheral = peripheral
        connectPeripheral.delegate = self
        centralManager.connect(connectPeripheral, options: nil)
    }

}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    charDictionary = [:]
    peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
}
```

Comment: You will need a property which is an array of `CBPeripheral` so that you can track all of the peripherals you are currently connected to.

Comment: Thanks! It's work. I use dictionary [String: CBPeripheral].